# Ribbon in Outlook for CRM greyed out

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I've installed the client for Outlook (v. 2013 both CRM and Outlook). Now, the ribbon is greyed out. After some thinking, googling and lamenting I got nothing to go on.

The current user (me) is created and the rolls are assigned (admin and custom). I can access the thing via the web client. Everything's been reinstalled, restarted, rebooted, re-whatever-I-could-think-of.

Still - no cookies!

What can that depend on? How to trouble-shoot it?

When I access the side menu in Outlook and its CRM tab, it's the same story. Everything is deactivated, although the organization is set to be syncable to and working. No error messages in the log, as far I could see...

[image]

I have more or less followed [everything that I could find](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/dynamicscrmsupportblog/archive/2012/12/05/crm-for-outlook-client-add-in-disabled.aspx) on the net. Most blogs/posts are just copies of the same material.

All the addins listed in the settings are like so. The plugin is listed twice. When I uninstall, **both** listings disappear. Then, when I reinstall, **both** are back. Weird.

[image]

Comment: Did you check out the list of COM Add-ins in Outlook?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes. It's listed there (under active, not inactive ones). In fact, now that I take a look at it, it seems to be there twice. Didn't notice that before (or it wasn't like so - we'll never know, hehe). Removing and reinstalling makes **both** disappear, then reappear **twice again**... Suggestions? (I also added a screenie from the settings.

Comment: Check out the windows registry keys for add-ins. It look like you need to remove duplicates.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Done. No issues reported in the client's log file. It says I'm ready to use my organization. However, the ribbon stays grey... I suspect issues with authentication **prior** the connection (such as obtaining the list of organizations and such) are resolved but there's still some issues **post** connection (while actually synchronizing). Not sure how to trouble-shoot (other than by google, of course).

Comment: Do you have Lync Installed ... if so have you attempted to uninstall Lync to see if that could be the problem(I have had issues with Lync and my Outlook add-on) also have you seen this fix : https://czerw.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/crm-client-for-outlook-configuration-issues/

Answer (score 0):

I had a user with a similar problem and I enabled Microsoft Access Outlook Add-In for Data Collection and Publishing, restarted outlook and it worked. Hope this helps.